Node-Red Dashboard 2.0 - Using a ui-template to create a button to click to toggle a relay on and off. Not working as expected
When I click the button in the dashboard, nothing happens.  The formatting of the box, text, and image don't change when clicked, and the relay isn't switched on.  When clicking on the Set Off and Set On inject nodes in the node-red flow, the relay triggers.  There is an issue with my template that I'm having difficulty pin-pointing.
JSON of the flow config:
[
    {
        "id": "f81abdae852f91a6",
        "type": "rpi-gpio out",
        "z": "a4a0218f2135997c",
        "name": "",
        "pin": "2",
        "set": true,
        "level": "1",
        "freq": "",
        "out": "out",
        "bcm": true,
        "x": 480,
        "y": 260,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "ea5563793dce06bd",
        "type": "ui-template",
        "z": "a4a0218f2135997c",
        "group": "7b7cd476eb00b2df",
        "page": "",
        "ui": "",
        "name": "Test",
        "order": 0,
        "width": "0",
        "height": "0",
        "format": "<script>\n    (function(scope) {\n        scope.$watch('msg', function(msg) {\n            const button = document.getElementById('toggleButton');\n            const icon = document.getElementById('buttonIcon');\n            const text = document.getElementById('buttonText');\n\n            console.log('Incoming message:', msg);\n\n            if (msg && msg.payload === '0') {\n                button.classList.add('on');\n                icon.src = './assets/winch_black.png';\n                text.style.color = '#000000';\n            } else if (msg && msg.payload === '1') {\n                button.classList.remove('on');\n                icon.src = './assets/winch_white.png';\n                text.style.color = '#ffffff';\n            }\n        });\n\n        scope.toggleButton = function() {\n            const button = document.getElementById('toggleButton');\n            const icon = document.getElementById('buttonIcon');\n            const text = document.getElementById('buttonText');\n\n            if (button.classList.contains('on')) {\n                button.classList.remove('on');\n                icon.src = './assets/winch_white.png';\n                text.style.color = '#ffffff';\n                scope.send({ payload: '1', topic: scope.msg.topic });\n            } else {\n                button.classList.add('on');\n                icon.src = './assets/winch_black.png';\n                text.style.color = '#000000';\n                scope.send({ payload: '0', topic: scope.msg.topic });\n            }\n        };\n    })(scope);\n</script>\n\n<style>\n    .button {\n        width: 128px;\n        height: 128px;\n        background-color: #2d3136;\n        border-radius: 20px;\n        display: flex;\n        flex-direction: column;\n        align-items: center;\n        justify-content: flex-start;\n        padding: 12px;\n        cursor: pointer;\n        transition: background-color 0.3s;\n    }\n\n    .button img {\n        width: 64px;\n        height: 64px;\n        margin-top: 14px;\n    }\n\n    .button p {\n        margin: 0;\n        margin-top: 8px;\n        color: #ffffff;\n        font-size: 14px;\n        transition: color 0.3s;\n    }\n\n    .button.on {\n        background-color: #66b5f8;\n    }\n\n    .button.on img {\n        content: url('./assets/winch_black.png');\n    }\n\n    .button.on p {\n        color: #000000;\n    }\n</style>\n\n<div class=\"button\" id=\"toggleButton\" ng-click=\"toggleButton()\">\n    <img src=\"./assets/winch_white.png\" alt=\"Settings Icon\" id=\"buttonIcon\">\n    <p id=\"buttonText\">Winch</p>\n</div>",
        "storeOutMessages": true,
        "passthru": true,
        "resendOnRefresh": true,
        "templateScope": "local",
        "className": "",
        "x": 310,
        "y": 260,
        "wires": [
            [
                "f81abdae852f91a6"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "fb1784fe33113bdc",
        "type": "inject",
        "z": "a4a0218f2135997c",
        "name": "Set Off",
        "props": [
            {
                "p": "payload",
                "v": "1",
                "vt": "str"
            }
        ],
        "repeat": "",
        "crontab": "",
        "once": false,
        "onceDelay": 0.1,
        "topic": "",
        "x": 150,
        "y": 220,
        "wires": [
            [
                "ea5563793dce06bd"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "68fcf6f4a0223cf9",
        "type": "inject",
        "z": "a4a0218f2135997c",
        "name": "Set On",
        "props": [
            {
                "p": "payload",
                "v": "0",
                "vt": "str"
            }
        ],
        "repeat": "",
        "crontab": "",
        "once": false,
        "onceDelay": 0.1,
        "topic": "",
        "x": 150,
        "y": 300,
        "wires": [
            [
                "ea5563793dce06bd"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "7b7cd476eb00b2df",
        "type": "ui-group",
        "name": "Winch",
        "page": "9b39b0acf751f2fc",
        "width": "2",
        "height": "1",
        "order": 1,
        "showTitle": false,
        "className": "",
        "visible": "true",
        "disabled": "false"
    },
    {
        "id": "9b39b0acf751f2fc",
        "type": "ui-page",
        "name": "Control",
        "ui": "544efb97afe2f6dc",
        "path": "/home",
        "icon": "home",
        "layout": "grid",
        "theme": "65dfab5792fc2a06",
        "order": 1,
        "className": "",
        "visible": false,
        "disabled": "false"
    },
    {
        "id": "544efb97afe2f6dc",
        "type": "ui-base",
        "name": "My Dashboard",
        "path": "/dashboard",
        "includeClientData": true,
        "acceptsClientConfig": [
            "ui-notification",
            "ui-control"
        ],
        "showPathInSidebar": false,
        "navigationStyle": "none"
    },
    {
        "id": "65dfab5792fc2a06",
        "type": "ui-theme",
        "name": "Default Theme",
        "colors": {
            "surface": "#2d3136",
            "primary": "#66b5f8",
            "bgPage": "#212529",
            "groupBg": "#212529",
            "groupOutline": "#212529"
        },
        "sizes": {
            "pagePadding": "12px",
            "groupGap": "12px",
            "groupBorderRadius": "20px",
            "widgetGap": "12px"
        }
    }
]

Here are the contents of the template for visibility:
<script>
    (function(scope) {
        scope.$watch('msg', function(msg) {
            const button = document.getElementById('toggleButton');
            const icon = document.getElementById('buttonIcon');
            const text = document.getElementById('buttonText');

            console.log('Incoming message:', msg);

            if (msg && msg.payload === '0') {
                button.classList.add('on');
                icon.src = './assets/winch_black.png';
                text.style.color = '#000000';
            } else if (msg && msg.payload === '1') {
                button.classList.remove('on');
                icon.src = './assets/winch_white.png';
                text.style.color = '#ffffff';
            }
        });

        scope.toggleButton = function() {
            const button = document.getElementById('toggleButton');
            const icon = document.getElementById('buttonIcon');
            const text = document.getElementById('buttonText');

            if (button.classList.contains('on')) {
                button.classList.remove('on');
                icon.src = './assets/winch_white.png';
                text.style.color = '#ffffff';
                scope.send({ payload: '1', topic: scope.msg.topic });
            } else {
                button.classList.add('on');
                icon.src = './assets/winch_black.png';
                text.style.color = '#000000';
                scope.send({ payload: '0', topic: scope.msg.topic });
            }
        };
    })(scope);
</script>

<style>
    .button {
        width: 128px;
        height: 128px;
        background-color: #2d3136;
        border-radius: 20px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        padding: 12px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: background-color 0.3s;
    }

    .button img {
        width: 64px;
        height: 64px;
        margin-top: 14px;
    }

    .button p {
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 8px;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 14px;
        transition: color 0.3s;
    }

    .button.on {
        background-color: #66b5f8;
    }

    .button.on img {
        content: url('./assets/winch_black.png');
    }

    .button.on p {
        color: #000000;
    }
</style>

<div class="button" id="toggleButton" ng-click="toggleButton()">
    <img src="./assets/winch_white.png" alt="Settings Icon" id="buttonIcon">
    <p id="buttonText">Winch</p>
</div>

I'm trying to get a box in the dashboard to be clickable, changing the formatting of the box and toggling the relay connected to the Raspberry Pi 5's GPIOs.
When off, the box should look like this and set the relay to OFF:

When on, the box should look like this and set the relay to ON:


Try replacing ng-click="toggleButton() with @click="toggleButton()" in your ui-template node
